# Are there different .net CLRs for x86 and x64?

Tags: .net, x86, clr, native

Are there different .net CLRs for x86 and x64  ?

```
decimal i = 89;
i=i++;
```

Will above code have different native code generated by CLR on x86, x64 ?

**UPDATE:**
   If yes then when i install visual studio on my machine will install both the CLR versions independent of machine bits ?  Has it to do something with performance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is both a 32-bit and a 64-bit specific JITter. Which one your code will run under depends both on the host environment/process that loaded the CLR and the assembly itself.

When you build your assemblies you can choose whether it will target x86, x64, or "AnyCPU".

- AnyCPU will run as 32-bit under 32-bit and 64-bit under 64-bit.
- 32-bit will run as 32-bit on 32-bit and will run under WOW64 on 64-bit.
- 64-bit won't run under 32-bit, but will run as 64-bit on 64-bit.

There is also a case for 'legacy' assemblies which were built before this facility was introduced. I believe they act the same as the 32-bit ones.

Note that if your assembly has any 32-bit native dependencies then you should also mark it as 32-bit, otherwise it will be loaded as 64-bit in a 64-bit environment and the dependencies will fail to load.

To answer your updated questions:

64-bit machines will have both the 32-bit and the 64-bit CLR installed.  The 32-bit is needed to run 32-bit assemblies under WOW64. (For example, Visual Studio is 32-bit!)

32-bit can sometimes run faster because pointers are smaller, so there is less cache/memory wasted on them. On the other hand, 64-bit mode has more registers available for the JITter to use. It depends on the characteristics of the code.

Comment: when i install visual studio on my machine will install both the CLR versions independent of machine bits ? Has it to do something with performance ?

Comment: Really great answer. thanks for this.  Few questions  arised > 1. you say "64-bit machines will have both the 32-bit and the 64-bit CLR installed."  Qst - when and who installs it ? You must be having good information source links ... please share .